# Reading many CSVs in parallel slows down in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, multiprocessing

I have 100k+ CSV files (on average between 2MB to 10MB in size) stored on S3.

I need to read each file individually to assign an id to the CSV before compiling all the CSVs together into a single `DataFrame`. I have a script which works well and distributes well for up to 2k files. After about 2k files are read and processed, the job slows down and the executors are not working (down to 5% of CPU usage). What could the cause be? I don't think its a partition issue since the files aren't that big. Is it related to starting thousands of processes in Python?

Is it better to write an extra column to the CSVs (so that the job can run async) and then read all the CSVs at once? Is re-writing the script in batch the best solution?

This is the script.

```
files = list(bucketObj.objects.filter(Prefix=subfolder))
p = ThreadPool(numNodes)
logDFs = p.map(lambda x: process(bucket, columns, x) , files)
df = unionAll(*logDFs)

def process(bucket, nameMap, item):
    logId = item['id']
    key = item['file']
    try:
        logger.info(key + ' ---- Start\n')
        fLog = spark.read.option("header", "true").option(
            "inferSchema", "true").csv(buildS3Path(bucket) + key)
        fLog = assignID(fLog)

        return fLog

    except Exception as e:
        logger.info(key + ' ---- ERROR ---- ')
```

**Update #1**
I have reworked the code to read each CSV in parallel and append a column with the id and save. Then a separate script reads in batch the files which are now in the proper format. This also has the same issue - runs fast for the first 1500 files then slows down. The project is being run on AWS EMR with 10 workers.

**Update #2**
I have reworked the script to work in batches of size 500. This is running better but the workers are engaging only at 10% CPU in steady state (they engage up to 60% at the beginning).

```
for i in range(0,numBatches):
    p = ThreadPool(numNodes)
    if (i == numBatches):
        fileSlice = fileErrList[i*batchSize:]
    else:
        fileSlice = fileErrList[i*batchSize:((i+1)*batchSize)]

    logger.info('\n\n\n --------------- \n\n\n')
    logger.info('Starting Batch : ' + str(i))
    logger.info('\n\n\n --------------- \n\n\n')
    p.map(lambda x: addIdCsv(x, bucket, logger), fileSlice)
    p.terminate()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a working solution, and also learned what to avoid:

1. In the case that you're forced to load each file individually before doing aggregate ETL, do only the necessary transformation on the individual file level. In this case, only add the id to the file.
2. By experience, unioning 100,000+ files isn't efficient. It is better to save new files which can be loaded all at once. In my case I converted each csv to a parquet file with the added ID column. I specified the schema on write to avoid issues on the read. Reading then becomes as easy as `spark.read.parquet('filepath')`
3. Make sure the spark executor configurations are tuned to the number of spawned threads. To maximize worker cpu, let each executor use exactly one core. On my cluster, I have 10 workers each having 4 cores and 4GB of memory. Each executor needs to have allocated memory overhead (min 384MB). I added the following configurations to the `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf` to the master node on EMR.

   ```
   spark.executor.memory            500M
   spark.executor.memoryOverhead    500M
   spark.executor.cores             1
   ```

   Then I spawn 40 threads: `p = ThreadPool(40)`
4. I wrote a bash script to run spark-submit on batches of 10,000 files.
5. After you the aggregate read, you can do the rest of your ETL.